# RxJava retry based on logic

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

Here is the case, I have an API call using Retrofit that might fail due to a network error. If it fails we will show an error message with a retry button. When the user presses the retry button we need to retry the latest Observable again.

Possible Solutions:

1. Retry: Retry should be used before subscribing to the observable and it will immediately resubscribe again if an error happens and that is what I don't want, I need to resubscribe only if the user pressed the Retry button.
2. RetryWhen: It Will keep trying as you emit items until you emit an Observable error then it will stop. Same issue here, I need to not start the retry process unless the user decides to.
3. Resubscribe to the same Observable: This solution will start emitting the Observable items, the problem with this is that we are using the cache operator, so if one Observable failed, we got the failed item cached and when we do subscribe again, we got the same error again.

Are there any other solutions to go with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go with retryWhen, which parameter - Func1 - returns an Observable which indicates when a retry should happen. For example :

```
PublishSubject<Object> retryButtonClicked = PublishSubject.create();

Observable
        .error(new RuntimeException())
        .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("error"))
        .retryWhen(observable -> observable.zipWith(retryButtonClicked, (o, o2) -> o))
        .subscribe();

retryButtonClicked.onNext(new Object());
```

every time retryButtonClicked emmits an event, Observable will be retried

Here's also an example - https://gist.github.com/benjchristensen/3363d420607f03307dd0

Comment: No retries happen at all, I think that retryWhen doesn't work as you explain it, the first time retyWhen calls the zipWith and didn't receive an emitted item due to the user didn't click the button yet, it will give up retrying and swallow the error.

Comment: retryWhen is not called when error happens, it's called at the observable creation time, just once, and it returns an Observable that indicates when to retry. The code I posted above prints "error" twice.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working, it was my mistake when I applied it into my code..can you please explain or point me to anything useful regarding why I should not use the subscriber and use the doONext, doOnError instead?

Comment: so to clarify. using the `retryWhen(` operator with `cache(` you can force a cache bust?

Comment: @krp If there is no internet I want to retry connect when the user clicks on the retry button. Your answer does not work with me. I'm using a single observable with retrofit