# RxJava onErrorResumeNext scheduler

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have an observable which might fail with a special exception in which case I want to show a dialog with a retry button. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30840306/1348215) answer, but it doesn't quite do what I want. I wasn't able to use `retryWhen` to solve my problem, so instead I used `onErrorResumeNext`. If you can come up with a way to do the same with `retryWhen`, please tell.

Right now I have this piece of code:

```
public Observable<Order> proceedWithOrdering(Activity activity) {
    return apiService.createOrder()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .compose(applyRetryLogic(activity))
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

public <T extends ApiResponse> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applyRetryLogic(Activity activity) {
    return observable -> observable
            .onErrorResumeNext(retry(observable, activity))
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

public <T> Func1<Throwable, ? extends Observable<? extends T>> retry(Observable toRetry, Activity activity) {
    return throwable -> {
        if (throwable instanceof NetworkException) {
            MaterialDialog dialog = retryDialog(activity);
            View retry = dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE);
            View cancel = dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.NEGATIVE);
            Observable<Object> retryClick = RxView.clicks(retry).map(o -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                return o;
            });
            Observable<Object> cancelClick = RxView.clicks(cancel).flatMap(o -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            });

            dialog.show();

            return Observable.amb(retryClick, cancelClick)
                    .flatMap(o -> toRetry.compose(applyRetryLogic(activity)));
        } else {
            return Observable.error(throwable);
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that the `call` inside the `retry` gets executed not on the main thread and it raises the `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` exception.

The question is - how do I force it to be executed on the main thread? As you can see, I have already tried doing `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` right after both `compose` and `onErrorResumeNext` with no luck.

I have tested my code using simple observables that don't operate on separate threads and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by `flatMap`ping a `PublishSubject` which is then updated once the relevant button is pressed. Here is a classical Java Swing example.

```
public class RetryWhenEnter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger d = new AtomicInteger();
        Observable<Integer> source = Observable.just(1);

        source.flatMap(v -> {
            if (d.incrementAndGet() < 3) {
                return Observable.error(new RuntimeException());
            }
            return Observable.just(v);
        })
        .retryWhen(err -> {
            return err.flatMap(e -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " Error!");
                PublishSubject<Integer> choice = PublishSubject.create();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    int c = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                        e.toString() + "\r\nRetry?", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if (c == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        choice.onNext(1);
                    } else {
                        choice.onCompleted();
                    }
                });
                return choice;
            });
        }).subscribe(System.out::println, 
                Throwable::printStackTrace);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Or use `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` just before `onErrorResumeNext` or when using `retryWhen`: `retryWhen(o -> o.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())...)`.

**Edit 2**
I've rolled back the change so the answer is meaningful again.

Comment: I like the second solution more than the `retryWhen` one, thank you. I have adapted your first solution for Android and posted it as a separate answer for other users to see.

Comment: This `retryWhen(o -> o.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())...)` helped me. Upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of solving my problem using `retryWhen` (thanks @akarnokd):

```
public <T extends ApiResponse> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applyRetryLogic(Activity activity) {
    return observable -> observable
            .retryWhen(err -> err.flatMap(throwable -> {
                L.d(Thread.currentThread() + " Error!");
                if (throwable instanceof NetworkException) {
                    PublishSubject<Integer> choice = PublishSubject.create();
                    activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        MaterialDialog dialog = retryDialog(activity);
                        View retry = dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.POSITIVE);
                        View cancel = dialog.getActionButton(DialogAction.NEGATIVE);
                        RxView.clicks(retry).subscribe(o -> {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            choice.onNext(1);
                        });
                        RxView.clicks(cancel).subscribe(o -> {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            choice.onError(throwable);
                        });

                        dialog.show();
                    });
                    return choice;
                } else {
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            }));
}
```