# What is the difference between retryUntil and retryWhen in RXJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to know the difference between `retryUntil` and `retryWhen` in RXJava.

I have a button called Retry and when the user clicks on it the connection must retry again to get data from the server, What is the best way to do that?

There is no code because I want only to know what is the best scenario only to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you do not quite correctly understand what these operators are for.  Read about these operators here: https://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/

As per your task: you have a "downloadList()" method.  You call it and if you receive an error you display, for example, a dialog with a "repeat" button.  Then the user clicks on the "repeat" button and the "downloadList()" method is called.  This is how the function of the "repeat" button is done.

Comment: How to use retry with delay every 5 seconds?

Comment: My problem like this but the answer in that question not clear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839858/rxjava-retry-based-on-logic