# How can I retry to connect with the server using RXJava and Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-java2

**Code**

```
new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL_FILES).addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(RetrofitInterface.class).getCountries().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<CountryModel>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {
        MainActivity.activityMainBinding.activityMainLinearProgressIndicatorLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull List<CountryModel> countryModels) {
        fragmentCountriesBinding.fragmentCountriesRecyclerViewCountries.setAdapter(new CountriesAdapter(requireContext(), countryModels));
        MainActivity.activityMainBinding.activityMainLinearProgressIndicatorLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
        MainActivity.activityMainBinding.activityMainLinearProgressIndicatorLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (!MainActivity.isNetworkConnected(requireContext()))
            Snackbar.make(MainActivity.activityMainBinding.getRoot(), R.string.no_internet, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setMaxInlineActionWidth(1).setAction(R.string.retry, view ->
            {

            }).show();
        else
            Snackbar.make(MainActivity.activityMainBinding.getRoot(), R.string.something_went_wrong, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setMaxInlineActionWidth(1).show();
    }
});
```

**RetrofitInterface**

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {

    @GET("GetCountries.php")
    Single<List<CountryModel>> getCountries();

}
```

**CountryModel**

```
public class CountryModel {

    private int countryId;
    private String countryName, countryIcon;

    public int getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public String getCountryIcon() {
        return countryIcon;
    }

}
```

As you can see inside the `onError` method, I want when the user clicks on the retry button must retry the call with the server again.

I read the articles talking about `retryWhen` method and tried to understand this image, but I can't understand it. And I don't know how to use it with my scenario.

[image: The Image]

My problem is like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839858/rxjava-retry-based-on-logic) exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn’t reach a solution, so I decided to use `retryUntil` instead of `retryWhen`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple and just a temporary/hack rather than spending couple of days using retryWhen().

- In the code below, I encapsulate your request call to a function.
- If there is a network error, just do a recursive call with the function until it will be successful.

  ```
    private void sendRequest(){
        new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL_FILES).addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(RetrofitInterface.class).getCountries().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<CountryModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {
                MainActivity.activityMainBinding.activityMainLinearProgressIndicatorLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull List<CountryModel> countryModels) {
                fragmentCountriesBinding.fragmentCountriesRecyclerViewCountries.setAdapter(new CountriesAdapter(requireContext(), countryModels));
                MainActivity.activityMainBinding.activityMainLinearProgressIndicatorLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
                MainActivity.activityMainBinding.activityMainLinearProgressIndicatorLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (!MainActivity.isNetworkConnected(requireContext()))
                    Snackbar.make(MainActivity.activityMainBinding.getRoot(), R.string.no_internet, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setMaxInlineActionWidth(1).setAction(R.string.retry, view ->
                    {

                    }).show();
                 // IF NO NETWORK AVAILABLE just do recursive call of the method
               sendRequest();
                else
                    Snackbar.make(MainActivity.activityMainBinding.getRoot(), R.string.something_went_wrong, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setMaxInlineActionWidth(1).show();
            }
        });
    }
  ```

Comment: I know this method but I need radical solution